# Plot a true linear relationship on a log axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to plot the line for a linear relationship (or several linear relationships), where one axis has a log scale, and for the line to show the true linear relationship (i.e. not a straight line on the actual plot), as below?

[image: excel mockup]

The following code plots what appears on the plot as a straight line, but because the y-axis is a log scale it doesn't plot a true linear relationship.

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(x, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5, shape = 20) +
  xlab('Index of Multiple Deprivation (2015)') +
  ylab('Average network distance to nearest 2ha+ greenspace (m)') +
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se = FALSE)
```

It produces the following plot:

[image: ggplot version]

EDIT: reproducible example

```
ggplot(diamonds[1:5000, ],  aes(x = carat, y = price, colour = cut)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5, shape = 20) +
  xlim(0.5, 1.5) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(2500, 3000, 3500, 4000), limits = c(2500, 4000)) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se = FALSE)
```

Produces the following plot:

[image: reproducible diamonds example]

As you can see, although the y-axis has a log scale, the lines are still *literally* straight lines.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought `coord_trans(y = "log10")`, but I get an error combining that with the `geom_smooth`. Your best bet may be to fit the model outside of `ggplot`.

Comment: the example code only produces that plot if you have `df.m`

Comment: Yeah, to make it reproducible it would be nice to use a built-in dataset. `diamonds[1:5000, ]`, with `x = carat, y = price, color = cut` would work as a nice example.